# The ImageBase's Address of Excutable file

Tags: windows, exe, memory-address, portable-executable, ollydbg

Why does the ImageBase is difference between CFF and OllyDbg?

[image]

Comment: anything else I can add to my answer to help you understand this better?

Answer (score 1):

CFF is showing you static analysis, meaning it's just reading the file from disk not debugging it at runtime, showing you the "Preferred ImageBase" from the PE header, this is where the binary wants to be loaded at runtime.

When you do dynamic analysis such as with ollydbg it's showing you the values in the PE header at runtime, ImageBase will hold the current ImageBase, not the preferred one from disk.  But when you read DllCharacteristics from the [optional PE header](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx) you will see it is set to 0x8140.

The `0x0040 = IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE` meaning Address Space Layout Randomisation is enabled, causing the Windows loader to load modules into random addresses in effort to make exploits more difficult because hard coded jmps and addresses will not be accurate.

The exploit developers now need to calculate everything at runtime, well unless you use Windows 8 or 10 because a [bug has been causing ASLR](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/windows-8-and-later-fail-to-properly-apply-aslr-heres-how-to-fix/) to not work correctly...